Can someone please help me get samba setup on my raspberry pi so I can connect it to my computer and Haas Machine Center?
I am loosing my patience with this and I just need it to work! I would even be willing to pay someone to help me get this going. Ok, here is the back story. I have a Haas VF2 Machine center that only has an ethernet port for file sharing. So my Haas logs into Samba using a username and password through the ethernet port connected directly to the raspberry pi. That part of the system seems to work well. Now my raspberry Pi connects to my WIFI. This is how I would like to save the files to the raspberry pi from my computer. So, quick overview. I am saving NC files to my Raspberry Pi over wifi from my windows pc so that my Haas Machine can pull them off the raspberry pi to run the NC program.
I had this system up and running. But now, all of a sudden, when I boot up my Haas Mill, I cannot connect to the server from my computer. When I shut down my haas mill, I can reconnect again. Please Help Me! I want to get this working so bad, it saves so much time when transferring files. I don't even really know where to start anymore...
This is what I have added to my smb.conf
[haas]
Comment = Haas File Server
path = /home/cedesigns/Desktop/haas
Browseable = yes
Writeable = yes
only guest=no
create mask=0777
directory mask=0777
public = yes
Guest ok = yes

Also, I know this allows anyone to access this server. I am not too worried about it, as its just machine tool paths, but I would not be opposed to making it private.
Thank you for your help!
[EDIT:]
Following is a "schematic" of sorts to better illustrate the interconnections:






I've edited your question (added a "schematic") in an effort to better explain what you're trying to do, and where I suspect the problem is. IOW, I suspect your issue boils down to a TCP/IP networking issue: "How do I get my RPi to connect to both the WiFi on my LAN, and the Haas Mill over Ethernet?".
The good news is that I'm sure there's a solution for this issue - assuming my suspicion is correct. Perhaps someone here can answer your question as it stands now, but I'm not that someone. Before spending time working out a solution, I'd like for you to edit your question to add some important details. Specifically:

What OS version are you running on your RPi? This is important b/c 'bookworm's network manager is "NetworkManager"/nmcli; 'bullseye's network manager is dhcpcd. That is - unless you've changed things???

We need some details on how networking is configured on your Haas Mill. Is there a network config file; is it strictly a DHCP client - or what?


Without jumping to conclusions, my initial thought runs toward using socat to forward traffic between your RPi and the Haas Mill. Another possibility is to set your RPi up as an access point, but making the Ethernet the access point may be rather sticky. I found two sources that claim a config for this: 1 and 2, but have not tried either. As you are most familiar with your setup, perhaps a bit of reading/research on these options will yield an answer?
So this is the extent of this "answer" now... we can continue after you review & edit your question.

Thanks for the info! The schematic looks good. I have attached a picture of the os version, as well as the ip addresses I messed with on the ethernet port, and a picture of the networking configuration on my haas mill. I think maybe those options will help? Just to re-iterate, my haas mill cant do anything with internet access, but if you think the bridge will solve the problem, I am up for trying it.

It appears your Haas Mill network config has the possibility of using DHCP. Is there a reason you're not using that? DHCP is always the best & easiest way to connect everything on a LAN. IOW, set Haas Mill to use DHCP, Raspberry Pi is set to use DHCP by default. Connect Haas Mill to router/gateway via Ethernet. Then everything is connected! Haas Mill & RPi can connect. Have you tried this?

Makes sense. I can try that. But my router is a long ways away from my Haas mill, that's why I was connecting it to the ethernet on my PI. So just to verify, should I connect my Haas mill to my pi using an ether net cord, set everything to DHCP and see if it works? Wont I need to set up the bridge for that?

Ah, OK - I didn't know about the distance factor... So yeah, you'll probably need to set up a wifi -> ethernet bridge. Of the two references I cited in the answer, I think the first one (1) sounds more credible. However, it has the disadvantage of of having to replace NetworkManager with dhcpcd, and that step is not covered in the blog post  :(   However, there's a thread here that covers that.

Thanks you! So I was struggling to get things working. I went to a headless OS using SSH and was able to get samba up and going. I setup the network bridge and was able to get ethernet internet to my laptop through the RPi. But, once I set up the bridge, I cannot access the server anymore. I tried both ways, installing samba first then bridge or bridge first then samba. I cant get it to connect. Any ideas?

@RyanVine: Can you access anything from the Haas Mill... can you ping your gateway/router from the Haas Mill - or even your RPi? I'd suggest you set Samaba aside for now... first job is to get networking right. Once that's done, Samba will fall into place.

Ok. So I have the network bridge setup on the RPi, which is now running headless lite version OS. I have the ethernet cable going from the Haas mill to the RPi. Everything seems to work great as far as connections go. I am able to SSH into the RPi from my laptop and can see the RPi and IP from my router page. I am able to Ping my Haas mill from my router and my laptop and I get a response! Would you like me to install Samba now?

@RyanVine: Sounds like progress!  A question: did you say you had your Haas Mill pulling files from Samba previously? Can you briefly describe how that works (edit yr Question)? But yeah - go ahead with the Samba install.

Ok, installed the samba server using https://fernandezvictor.medium.com/raspberry-pi-as-samba-server-to-create-shared-folder-between-computers-cdea979092b8 I was able to connect to the server from both machines! We are in pretty good shape! The only thing, I have to log into the server from my laptop using the IP address. Is there a reason I cant use the Hostname? I am able to log into the server from my Mill using the Hostname. Also, I have one sambe user, cedesigns, for both my laptop and mill to log into the server. Is this ok?

@RyanVine: "The server" is the RPi?? ... reason I cant use the Hostname? A couple of thoughts: 1. avahi takes a while after a new IP is added, 2. Maybe (as in not sure) you will have to "bond" the interfaces. But that sounds like a new question to me... for now, use the IP & give avahi some time to come around. Re one samba user: I cannot imagine that would be an issue.

Thank you for the help!!

@RyanVine: It's working?? Did avahi "come around" & allow you to connect using hostnames?

Yes, it did come around! So far, it works great! Thank you for the help!
